# Read and Set the Preferences of "History Options" in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

Photoshop's History Panel has options:

[image]

Which has the following options:

[image]

Is there a way to read / write those preferences using Photoshop Scripting / ExtendScript?

Answer (score 2):

Usually options like that are accessible via a deeper layer of Photoshop preferences: Action Descriptors. But I think the ones you mentioned aren't available even in it: I had the same problem trying to find a way to change `Show Current Tool Only` in Tool Presets window. I tried to use [xbytor's Getter script](http://ps-scripts.sourceforge.net/xtools.html) but it didn't register any changes when I was setting this option on and off. So I don't think this option is available for scripting unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

The following seems to work on Photoshop CC 2019:

```
    var d = new ActionDescriptor();     
    var r = new ActionReference();     
    r.putProperty(stringIDToTypeID("property"), stringIDToTypeID("layerVisibilityChangesAreUndoable"));  
    r.putEnumerated(stringIDToTypeID("application"), stringIDToTypeID("ordinal"), stringIDToTypeID("targetEnum"));     
    d.putReference(stringIDToTypeID("null"), r);     

    var d1 = new ActionDescriptor();     
    d1.putBoolean(stringIDToTypeID("layerVisibilityChangesAreUndoable"), false);     

    d.putObject(stringIDToTypeID("to"), stringIDToTypeID("layerVisibilityChangesAreUndoable"), d1);  

    executeAction(stringIDToTypeID("set"), d, DialogModes.NO);
```

Comment: Interesting, the option is available in both CC2018 and CC2019 but it has a key only in CC2019: so this code works in CC2019 but not in CC2018. And this explains why I didn't find the key in my CC2018 while running a getter script.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes It Is Possible But Not As You Want**

Basically Photoshop Script DOM Have History State Option; But It Only Allows to jump back to History State and Revert It; So It Means You can control Which Step You Want to revert in script: See Below

[image]

**So Basically In Order to Revert To Any Step You Can Do Something Like This**

`var docRef = app.activeDocument;
 docRef.ActiveHistoryState = docRef.HistoryStates[1];`

**This Will Revert Your Work And Will Get Back To your 1st History State;
Or In Advance If You want To go to specific Step Use Prompt Like Below;**

`var docRef = app.activeDocument;
var step = prompt("Which step You wanna Go";"");
 docRef.ActiveHistoryState = docRef.HistoryStates[step];`

**But If You Want To access That Specific History Option I'm feared that It Is Possible to access via script;Refer Below Link For More Details; You Can Find More About It On Page [Page No .48](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/scripting/photoshop-cc-scripting-guide.pdf)**

[image]

I Know This Might Not What You want but hope It Helps You to understand Photoshops DOM;
-Regards Phoenix Design

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the effort. I am not after the History State of Photoshop. I am specifically after altering the the option `Make Layer Visibility Changes Undoable`. I think I saw once you can alter preferences of Photoshop using ExtendScript, hence I wonder if there is an option to access those.

Comment: Yeah I Thought So Since You specified it in 2nd picture; But as you can see it in Official Reference They Have No Such A option ;Will See If there is another options :)

Comment: See my answer above.

Comment: yeah mostly i didn't use actionDescriptor since i'm not well aware of it :) thanks for your script

Answer (score 1):

You can set non-linear history to true like this:

```
var idsetd = charIDToTypeID( "setd" );
var desc17 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
    var ref2 = new ActionReference();
    var idPrpr = charIDToTypeID( "Prpr" );
    var idCchP = stringIDToTypeID( "historyPreferences" );
    ref2.putProperty( idPrpr, idCchP );
    var idcapp = charIDToTypeID( "capp" );
    var idOrdn = charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" );
    var idTrgt = charIDToTypeID( "Trgt" );
    ref2.putEnumerated( idcapp, idOrdn, idTrgt );
desc17.putReference( idnull, ref2 );
var idT = charIDToTypeID( "T   " );
    var desc18 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc18.putBoolean(stringIDToTypeID("nonLinear"),true);
var idCchP = stringIDToTypeID( "historyPreferences" );
desc17.putObject( idT, idCchP, desc18 );
executeAction( idsetd, desc17, DialogModes.NO );
```

**Older answer:**
In Photoshop preferences file it is the byte next to "HstN" key with type of boolean. Strings are reversed due to its endianness. Far from perfect but it is readable. If someone changes this after PS start then you won't know it.

1 = enabled.

Settings is loaded/applied with PS startup and saved with PS quit.

[image]